# PHP get Image from Google Search

Tags: php, google-api

Is it possible / is there an API that gives me back the best first match for an image due to a term?

I have a list of cars and I want to send an API Request with e.g.

```
Audi A5
Audi A6
Audi S7
```

to get back the first result of Google Images.

Or is it not legal due to copyrights?